# How to update multiple list items in Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, listitem

I have a list in sharepoint online: ListA

This list has 1500 items and 7 columns. 4 of them are populated while 3 are not.

I also have a dataframe with 3 columns, to be used for populating: Status, Week, Delivery

I would like to update all the items, so that all 7 columns are populated.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': pd.Series(range(1,1500)), 'Week': pd.Series(range(1,1500)), 'Delivery': 
                     pd.Series(range(1,1500))})
```

I am fully authenticated.

I followed this example to update one list item:

```
# Open list object from portal
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=sharepoint_site_url)
ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_site_url, ctx_auth)
target_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title('ListA')

# Fetch list item object by id and set it's properties
item = target_list.get_item_by_id(item_id)
item.set_property('Status', '1')
item.set_property('Week', '1')
item.set_property('Delivery', '1')

# Update list item object and send request back to portal
item.update()
ctx.execute_query()
```

But I have 1500 items.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/2.0.0/)? If so, you can put the update code in a loop, you can get [all item](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/55252191cb7f729f044f61542dca309249c743fc/office365/sharepoint/lists/list.py#L164) as below:

```
items = target_list.items
```

BR